# Offline application shortcut 

Tags: html, offline-web-app

I have developed an application with HTML5. I want to know how I can make a shortcut/access-point URL icon to access my offline page.

Comment: You wanna have a link to a saved page in your web page that your currently creating with html5 ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no straight equivalent to the [createShortcut on the Gears Desktop API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_desktop.html) in HTML5.  The closest thing is [Protocol Handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#dom-navigator-registerprotocolhandler), but that's probably not a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `/path/favicon.ico` to your cache.manifest, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

If you mean a desktop shortcut, you can't do that through the app itself, have to use an external program.

Comment: no actually i want to create an shortcut-icon which will point to my offline page, in html5 or javascript but not with gear.